# How to make a device groupOwner in WifiDirect?

Tags: android, wifi-direct

I have developed a WiFi Direct Application and I used this code to differentiate between a groupOwner and other device. But groupOwner is always made randomly. I want to make sure that connecting device acts like a groupOwner every time a connection is made. My code :

```
if (info.groupFormed && info.isGroupOwner) {

     // GroupOwner     

   } else if (info.groupFormed) {


   }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use the property `groupOwnerIntent` of `WifiP2pConfig` object , which you pass to the connect() call. For example:

```
config.groupOwnerIntent = 15;
```

Value ranges between 0-15 , higher the value higher the possibility of becoming a groupOwner.

Answer (score 8):

If your goal is to make the device, which is advertising a service, also the group owner, then   on your `WifiP2pManager` instance call `createGroup` in the `onSuccess` callback of `addLocalService`

```
WifiP2pManager manager = (WifiP2pManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_P2P_SERVICE);
WifiP2pManager.Channel channel = serverManager.initialize(this, getMainLooper(), null);

HashMap<String, String> record = new HashMap<String, String>();

WifiP2pServiceInfo serviceInfo = WifiP2pDnsSdServiceInfo.newInstance("_hello", "_world._tcp", record);

//remove legacy group
manager.removeGroup(channel, null);

//advertise your service
manager.addLocalService(channel, serviceInfo, new WifiP2pManager.ActionListener() {

  @Override
  public void onFailure(int reason) {
  }

  @Override
  public void onSuccess() {
    //create group, making this device the owner of the group
    manager.createGroup(channel, null);
  }

});
```